# All X elements below Y, but before another, descendent, Y

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

```
<div n="a">
  . . . 
    . . .
      <spec>red</spec>
      <div n="d">
          . . . 
      </div>
      <spec>green</spec>
      . . .
         <div n="b">
            . . .
              <spec>blue</spec>
            . . .
         </div>
         <div n="c">
           <spec>yellow</spec>
         </div>
      . . .
    . . .
  . . .
</div>
```

**[Edited to remove the ambiguity Sean noticed. -- Thanks]**

When the current element is `<div n="a">`, I need an XPATH expression that returns the red and green elements, but not the blue and yellow ones, as `.//spec` does.

When the current element is `<div n="b">`, the same expression needs to return the blue element; when `<div n="c">`, the yellow element.

Something like `.//spec[but no deeper than another div if there is one]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In XSLT 1.0, assuming that the current node is a `div`:**

```
.//spec[generate-id(current())=generate-id(ancestor::div[1])]
```

**In XSLT 2.0 under the same assumptions**:

```
.//spec[ancestor::div[1] is current()]
```

**And a pure XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
for $this in .
     return
        $this//spec[ancestor::div[1] is $this]
```

---

**Full XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="div">
  <div n="{@n}"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   ".//spec[generate-id(current())=generate-id(ancestor::div[1])]"/>
==============
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<div n="a">
  . . .
    . . .
      <spec>red</spec>
      <spec>green</spec>
      . . .
         <div n="b">
            . . .
              <spec>blue</spec>
            . . .
         </div>
         <div n="c">
           <spec>yellow</spec>
         </div>
      . . .
    . . .
  . . .
</div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<div n="a"/>
<spec>red</spec>
<spec>green</spec>
==============
  <div n="b"/>
<spec>blue</spec>
==============
  <div n="c"/>
<spec>yellow</spec>
==============
```

---

**Full XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="div">

  <div n="{@n}"/>
  <xsl:sequence select=".//spec[ancestor::div[1] is current()]"/>
===================================
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced:**

```
<div n="a"/>
<spec>red</spec>
<spec>green</spec>
===================================
  <div n="b"/>
<spec>blue</spec>
===================================
  <div n="c"/>
<spec>yellow</spec>
===================================
```

---

**And using pure XPath 2.0 (no `current()`):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="div">

  <div n="{@n}"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="
    for $this in .
     return
        $this//spec[ancestor::div[1] is $this]"/>
===================================
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces the same correct result**:

```
<div n="a"/>
<spec>red</spec>
<spec>green</spec>
===================================
  <div n="b"/>
<spec>blue</spec>
===================================
  <div n="c"/>
<spec>yellow</spec>
===================================
```

Comment: Oh, Dimitre, I like that. (Yes, the current node would be a div.) So . and current() are the same node. A good use of current()! Why is generate-id needed, though?

Comment: @JPM, In XSLT 1.0 `generate-id(`) is often more efficient than `count(.|$ns2) = 1`. Also, do see the pure XPath 2.0 expression in the updated answer.

Comment: Why not just current()=ancestor::div[1]?

Comment: @Dimitre, I am not sure your XSLT 1.0 solution is correct. Would you have a look at how it applies to `Test Case 1` as I have included in my addendum?

Comment: @JPM, This would be wrong -- it compares the *string values* of the two operands -- not their identity.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, The OP clearly uses the term "descendant", not "sibling". Thereforeyour Test Case 1 is not relevant to this question, as one of the `div` elements is self-closing and doesn't have any `spec` descendants.

Comment: Sean is right that I wasn't fully clear. Dimitre is right on what I intended. I have edited the Q accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using XSLT 1.0, and you want to select `spec' children, all children, then with your desired 'current' node as the XSLT focus node, set the following variable...

```
<xsl:variable name="divs" select="*//div" />
```

Now you can select all `spec` descendants which are not preceded by a `div` descendant with this XPath expression...

```
//spec[not((preceding::div|ancestor::div)[count(. | $divs) = count($divs)])]
```

### Caveat

This should work, but I have not tested it. With this caution, I leave it as an exercise to the OP to test.

### Note

If you really desperately want an XPath expression that does not require you to declare an additional variable, **AND** you happen to be lucky enough that you already hold the current node in a node-set (lets call it $ref), the you could use this rather inefficient XPath expression...

```
$ref//spec[not((preceding::div|ancestor::div)[count(. | $ref/*//div) =
                                              count(    $ref/*//div)  ])]
```

### Addendum

Here is a test case that I may be referring to the comment streams.

Test Case 1 Input:

```
<div n="a">
      <spec>red</spec>
      <div n="x"/>
      <spec>green</spec>
      <div n="b">
        <spec>blue</spec>
      </div>
      <div n="c">
        <spec>yellow</spec>
      </div>
</div>
```

Test Case 1 Expected output:

- Should be just `red`

Comment: SeanB.Durkin, The OP clearly uses the term "descendant", not "sibling". Thereforeyour Test Case 1 is not relevant to this question, as one of the `div` elements is self-closing and doesn't have any `spec` descendants.